# Why Golang display different values when use different output function

Tags: go

I try to check when Golang return a local value as nil, then I use this code.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type S struct{}

func InitEfacePointer() interface{} {
    var s *S
    println(s)
    return s
}

func main() {
    s := InitEfacePointer()
    fmt.Println(s)
    //println(s)
}
```

The output is
0x0

But when I just use println to output value.

```
package main

type S struct{}

func InitEfacePointer() interface{} {
    var s *S
    println(s)
    return s
}

func main() {
    s := InitEfacePointer()
    println(s)
}
```

The output changed to 
0x0
(0x93d40,0x0)

Could anyone explain the mechanism of this behavior? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `fmt.Println` and builtin `println` are very different matteres: they are different both in implentation and in purpose. `fmt.Println` deals with many complex cases using reflect while `println` only deal with some base cases and is only for "bootstrap or debug" (as the spec says).

In this specific case, you are printing an `interface{}` you returned from `InitEfacePointer()`. The `fmt.Println` looks into the interface using reflect and gets the underlying data: a nil pointer to a string and it then prints it out: `0x0`. On the other hand, builtin `println` takes the interface and by magic of the compiler (or not), it recognize it is an interface. As [this post](https://research.swtch.com/interfaces), golang interface are auctually two pointers, one to information about the type stored and one to the underlying data. So the builtin `println`goes into the interface details, `0x93d40` being the "type info" and `0x0` being the underlying data. (The first `0x0` is from the function call).

Furthermore, testing whether the returned interface is `nil` seems like a common mistake. Read here: https://golang.org/doc/faq#nil_error

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't be using the [builtin println](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#println), it clearly states:

> The println built-in function formats its arguments in an
>   implementation-specific way and writes the result to standard error.
>   Spaces are always added between arguments and a newline is appended.
>   Println is useful for bootstrapping and debugging; it is not
>   guaranteed to stay in the language.

And the [spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Bootstrapping) also mentions:

> Current implementations provide several built-in functions useful
>   during bootstrapping. These functions are documented for completeness
>   but are not guaranteed to stay in the language. They do not return a
>   result.
>
> Implementation restriction: print and println need not
>   accept arbitrary argument types, but printing of boolean, numeric, and
>   string types must be supported.

This is it. `print` and `println` are useful debugging tools but should not be relied upon to:

- provide a specific output
- provide the same output on different platforms
- provide the same output over time
- exist

That said, I'm guessing that in your case it is printing the internal interface fields: a pointer to a type, and a value.